# Encrypting files in Mac OS: Are there any possible security issues with the AES - DMG encryption method via DiskUtility?

Tags: macos, security, encryption, truecrypt

I was wondering how the 256-AES encryption method contained in DiskUtility in Apple Mac OSX works compared to other open source encryption applications out there. This method is found under the Disk Utility application and creates a .DMG file in the end. Is there any possible security problems here for encrypting large files, (100 GB) vs. GnuPG, etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not any possible security problems. Really, it is about your preference and how it will be used. Whatever you are encrypting, if you are using it or will ever use it on anything other than a mac, GPG/PGP will be the way to go. If you are sticking to your mac guns, the easiest way will use Apples' utilities.

Also, avoid truecrypt as it has been discontinued and reasons are unclear and i remain skeptical as to why truecrypt discontinued their encryption tools.